# How can i make Windows 10 compress memory (RAM) more often?

Tags: windows-10, memory, compression

This Image:[image]

Shows why i want to do this, when i use my hackintosh (this is off-topic) on the same PC ram is compressed almost all the time, and it's way more snappy than in Windows 10, barely any memory is getting compressed, and paging is really slow when i try to re-open an application.

Answer (score 1):

Memory compression will not be a magic bullet:

- 3GB is simply not a realistic amount of RAM to run Windows 10. The Windows kernel just uses a lot more memory than a BSD-derived (such as OSX) and applications tend to use more as well.
- Seeing, that this is still DDR2 RAM the CPU power will not be great as well, so the CPU cost of memory compression will show up very noticably.
- Since Windows does a lot more disk access than OSX, you will also need more RAM as a disk cache to speed things up.

For a bare Windows 10 System start with 4GB RAM, if you use any memory-hungry applications don't stay below 8GB (RAM on eBay is less then 4$/GB). Or you might just consider retiring this 10+ years old machine - it wa never designed to run Windows 10. And I suspect you get other problems (e.g. GPU-related) as well.

Comment: Windows 10 continuously uses memory compression.  Just because you don’t agree with the answer doesn’t mean it isn’t an accurate helpful answer.

Comment: The answer is not helpful because it doesn't answer my question, not because it isn't accurate, it's just not helpful.

Comment: Might it be not helpful because the question relies on a false premise? You don't want to ask "How can I make Win10 compress more RAM?" (to which the answer would be "It already does as much as it can"), but "Why is the machine so laggy (if it is not on OSX)?". I tried to answer that, but you are welcome to shoot the messenger!

Comment: For some crazy reason, Windows 10 does not trigger the memory compression correctly. Try installing Windows 10 in a virtual machine, flag the virtual disk as a SSD, set RAM to 1 - 2 GB and see how Windows 10 suddenly does impressive memory compression all the time. With more RAM and on traditional hard disks, for whatever reason this helpful compression does not kick in at all, or only rarely. So even when memory pressure is extremely high, nothing can happen. This is a serious flaw that Microsoft somehow hasn't acknowledged yet. Windows 10 1511 did this way better, by the way.